# Get minimum of a object

Tags: livescript, prelude.ls

Firstly, good morning.

*PreludeLS* is able to get the minimum value of an array:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] |> minimum #=> 1
```

Now I figure out a way to get the `minimum-by` a **unknown key**. Let's suppose I have an object called `A` and it has 3 properties with 3 float values:

```
A =
  A: 3.2
  B: 4.2
  C: 4.7
```

And I want to return the **KeyValuePair** of the element with a lower  value:

```
{A: 32}
```

I can get the minimum by several objects by these objects having an equal index. How can I get the minimum by a unknown key?

- Yeah, I've already read 3 times LiveScript's documentation and 2 times PreludeLS documentation

Comment: Using only prelude-ls functions: `A |> obj-to-pairs >> (minimum-by (.1)) >> (->[it]) >> pairs-to-obj`  you can write it better if you define an `Obj.fold` for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
A |> obj-to-pairs |> minimum-by (.1)
#=> ['A', 3.2]

A |> obj-to-pairs |> minimum-by (.1) |> -> {(it.0): it.1}
#=> {A: 3.2}
```